# A mismatch between CENTOS 7 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7

Tags: linux, bash, centos, redhat

I have a bash script, it works on CENTOS fine, but when I want to run the script on Red Hat Enterprise Linux, I got the following error.

```
if [ "${line:(-2)}" == "nm" ]
 then
sub_sh=${line:31:8}
if [ $sub_sh != "test" ];
  then
sub_str=${line:0:10}
date_line=$(date --date=$sub_str '+%Y%m%d')
result=`expr $date_line - $yesterday`
if [ $result  -gt 1000 ];
then
 Rtime="${line##* }"
 pureqrt=${Rtime::-2}  #line 56
```

Error:

```
line 56: -2: substring expression < 0
```

Comment: I want to remove the last two characters ...could you please help me to rewrite this piece of code

Comment: FYI, CentOS 7 upgrades `bash` from 4.1 to 4.2 (which is the first version to allow negative indices).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the below script to remove the two last characters

```
#   in bash
#   pureqrt=${queryRtime::-2}
    pureqrt=$(echo $queryRtime | cut -d "m" -f 1)
----------------------------------------------
#command line 
 echo "2234ms" | cut -d "m" -f 1
 output : 2234
```

I appreciate your help